# Past Tense of "Do"

Tags: past-tense, do

Which sentence below is correct when using the past tense of "do"?

What I ***did*** to find out ***is*** that...

What I ***did*** to find out ***was*** that...

Comment: This looks like a dupe of that question at first, but is isn't. The issue here is the cleft. The issue there is a clause being used as the complement of an epistemic verb.

Comment: Could you give is full sentences for examples, please? I'll try and get your question reopened.

Comment: The actual duplicate is [“What it did was” versus “what it did is” versus “what it does is”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37809/what-it-did-was-versus-what-it-did-is-versus-what-it-does-is).